# Python Visualization

Tags: python

How can I rotate the labels?

I use the below code to visualize the data:

```
_, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(10, 6))

sns.countplot(x="Marital Status", data=df, ax=axes[0,0])
sns.countplot(x="Sex", data=df, ax=axes[0,1])
sns.countplot(x="Education", data=df, ax=axes[1,0])
sns.countplot(x="Workclass", data=df, ax=axes[1,1])
```

The displayed visualization is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(10, 6))
sns.countplot(x="Marital Status", data=df, ax=axes[0,0])
sns.countplot(x="Sex", data=df, ax=axes[0,1])
sns.countplot(x="Education", data=df, ax=axes[1,0])
sns.countplot(x="Workclass", data=df, ax=axes[1,1])
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```